# c++ deleting elements in a struct array

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

The code below takes a users input for 2 properties and stores it. I've been failing to find a way to **delete** the information on a property if it is removed from the market by prompting the user to enter the property-ID to be removed and also **update** the property details such as changing the Asking Price by prompting the user to enter the property-ID. My teacher recommended using a structure array which I have managed to do so far.

```
#include <iostream>                                           // takes users input and prints out output 
#include<conio.h>                                             // declares several useful library functions for performing "console input and output"
#include <stdio.h>                                            // compiler directive which stores standard input output 
using namespace std;                                          // defines the standard namespace 
struct Property                                               // declares the struct as Property 
{
   int ID[3];                                                // declare variable "ID" of data type interger to identify property ID 
   int Asking_Price;                                         // declare variable "Asking_Price" of data type interger to to identity the asking price for the property
   char Type[10];                                            // declare variable "Type" of data type char to identify the property type (detatched, semi-detatched, terraced, flat, commercial)
   char Address[20];                                         // declare variable "Address" of data type char to identify the property address
};
int main()  

{
   Property My_Property[2];                                      // declare the struct, the array and the number of array elements 
   for (int i=0;i<2;i++)                                         // for loop counts the number of properties from 1 to 5
   {
      cout << "\n  Details of property ID " << i + 1 << " are :\n"; // Prints out the property ID 

      cout << "\t Enter the property asking price : ";             // Prompts the user to enter asking price fopr the property  
      cin >> My_Property[i].Asking_Price;                          // Takes users input and stores it in the array 

      cout << "\t Please enter the property type: ";               //Prompts the user to enter the property type
      cin>>My_Property[i].Type;                                    //Takes users input and stores it in the array 

      cout << "\t Please enter the property address : ";           //Prompts the user to enter the property address
      cin >> My_Property[i].Address;                               //Takes users input and stores it in the array 
   }

   for (int j = 0;j<2;j++)                                      // for loop counts the property information for all properties entered
   {
      cout << "\n Information on property number " << j + 1 << " is :\n";  //Prints out the stored property ID
      cout << "\t Asking Price :" << My_Property[j].Asking_Price<<endl;  //Prints out the stored asking price for the property 
      cout << "\t Property Type : " << My_Property[j].Type<<endl;            //Prints out the stored property type 
      cout << "\t Address : " << My_Property[j].Address<<endl;           //Prints out the stored address for the property

   }

   for (int k=0;k<2;k++)    
   {
      cout << "\n Please enter the property ID for the property you would like to delete : \n ";
      cin>> My_Property[k].ID[3]; 

      if(My_Property[k].ID[3]>2)
      {
         cout<<"\n\n This property ID does not exist, press ENTER to try again: \n";
      }
      else
      {
         //trying to figure out the delete code

      }
      _getch(); //read characters from screen`enter code here`

   }
}
```

Comment: I can't spot anything that needs `delete` in your code.

Comment: Maybe look into the [Erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom).

Comment: Your teacher should have recommended a container class like `std::vector<Property>` and not dumb arrays.  There is no such thing as "deletion" when using arrays, since arrays cannot be resized.

Comment: Would it be possible to replace the stored information with a 'NULL' or empty space instead?

Comment: `cin>> My_Property[k].ID[3];` is accessing outside the array bounds. Undefined behavior.

Comment: Use array of pointers, but then you need to use `new` and `delete`, or just use std::vector

Comment: @Victoria Your array is stuck with 2 items, it doesn't matter what tricks you'll try, you have 2 items.  You would need another variable to keep track of the actual number of entries if you keep using arrays.  Using a container like vector actually will erase items when you erase them, not fake erasing them like in an array.

Comment: what kind of  variable can l use to keep track of entries? Sorry I'm still a beginner l don't know much about C++

Comment: You need an `int` to state how many valid entries there are.  The problem I see right away is that if you "delete" the first entry, you need to somehow know that there is 1 entry, and it is the second entry that is valid, not the first.  You then have to "move up" all the entries to cover up the hole created.  In other words, you're doing something `vector` does already.

Comment: Using a `std::vector` is a way better idea than using an array.

Comment: Thanks guys l will use a vector instead

Answer (score 1):

You can't actually delete an item from an array, since arrays have a fixed size.  The usual way to remove an item from a fixed-size container is to shift all subsequent elements down one space to overwrite the item you don't want.

```
Property props[10];
int prop_count = 0;
// Fill props somehow, incrementing prop_count each time you add an item
std::cout << "\n Please enter the property ID for the property you would like to delete : \n ";
int to_delete;
std::cin >> to_delete;
for (int i = to_delete + 1; i < prop_count; ++to_delete) {
    props[i - 1] = props[i];
}
prop_count -= 1;
```

This is more-or-less how `std::vector` works under the covers.

If you don't care about keeping all of your elements contiguous, you could add some way to mark a `Property` as deleted, but that tends to lead to more complicated code.

In the end, you should probably just use a re-sizable container like `std::vector`, at which point you could just call `std::vector::erase` to erase items from it.

Comment: Thank you @miles budnek l think l will rewrite the code and use a vector